# Difference between OverrideMetadata and default style

Tags: c#, wpf

While making a custom control which acts as a drag/drop target, I needed to set the `AllowDrop` property to `true`.  I initially used the following code, but found that the `Drop` event was never triggered:

EditorVisual.cs

```
public class EditorVisual : Control
{
    static EditorVisual()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(EditorVisual),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(EditorVisual)));
        AllowDropProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(EditorVisual),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));
    }
    // ...
    protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrop(e);
        // this is never called
    }
}
```

Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EditorVisual}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
    <!-- Uncomment to make things work -->
    <!-- <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" /> -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:EditorVisual}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Eventually, I narrowed it down to the way I was setting `AllowDrop` property.  Setting it in xaml or in the default style makes everything work properly... which confuses me.  Why is using a metadata override not sufficient to receive drag/drop events in a custom control?

**Edit:** Tested on Windows 8 using Visual Studio 2012 with .Net 4.0 on Any CPU - Debug.

Comment: How have you tested this? Just by looking at your code I can tell setting AllowDrop to true either in code or xaml is not gonna do the trick. Btw it doesn't matter if you use OverrideMetadata or Style.Setter. You will need to override/write few other methods in your control to make drag drop work. Can you show us those methods? Take a look at this link: http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html

Comment: @devhedgehog, yes, I have tested this.  Although you can override `OnDragEnter` and others to _enhance_ the experience, the minimum is `AllowDrop = true` and overriding `OnDrop`.  See msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx#Implementing_Drag_And_Drop

Comment: How have you tested this?

Comment: @devhedgehog, with visual studio, by running it with a debugger.  Dragging multiple objects, both from within the test app as well as from `explorer`.  Regardless of methodology, the `OnDrag*` family of events are called with `AllowDrop` set by style, but not by override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that doesn't work from the static constructor is that `AllowDrop` is an *inherited* dependency property. When you change its default value for the `EditorVisual` control, it does not propagate the value down the visual tree, which means the controls in the template you provided still have `AllowDrop` set to `false`. The hit testing during drag and drop encounters these controls and fails.

It's perfectly fine to use the style to set this value (or in the control's instance constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand now how you tried to test it.

Fact is if you wish to make drag and drop work you need to set AllowDrop to true. But AllowDrop is a framework property which allows inherits flag hence why all of your controls inside your ControlTemplate have also their AllowDrop set to true.

Now the thing is in WPF you cannot override metadata of a framework property that supports inherits flag. You kill the property inheriting when you do that.

You have two possibilities how to solve this.

1. Set the value in constructor:

   public EditorVisual()
   {
     this.AllowDrop = true;
   }
2. Set the value in your Style (this is what you already had).